# Jquery ui-sortable table column order

Tags: row, jquery-ui-sortable

I want to changing column order in table. I try to use jquery ui-sortable. 
When I finish a prototype in html I want to use it in Asp.Net GridView.

Problem:
When I pulled the column in its place is a hole formed

Link to test.html - where is example of my problem:
http://www.2shared.com/document/YpMqP3k6/test.html

Can someone help me how to remove the moving columns(empty column who was dragging).
For example when I was drag first column to the last positions then header of first column is empty. Body and footer sections of table are correct, but header don't.

Comment: I found jQuery UI widget for doing exactly that. - Demo http://jebaird.com/dev/project/dragtable/demo.htm
- Project https://github.com/jebaird/dragtable